# What eigenvalues of the linear operator should I consider?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have some linear operator $\mathcal O : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 $, and I find one real and two complex eigenvalues. Do I use consider only this real eigenvalue or I need to consider all of them?

Comment: How should we know, when we don't know what the goal is?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not really well-defined - it depends on why you are finding the eigenvalues. If you want to diagonalize $\mathcal{O}$ as a real operator, then the complex eigenvalues are irrelevant. If you want to extend scalars and treat $\mathcal{O}$ as an operator on $\mathbb{C}^3$ then they are relevant. If you want to find a basis with respect to which $\mathcal{O}$ is block diagonal, they are relevant, etc.